# Force computation of calculated columns in .xlsx imported via pd.ExcelFile

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl, calculated-columns

Suppose my `data.xlsx`'s first sheet contains some computed columns.

I'm trying to pull out a `pd.DataFrame` of that sheet that holds the computed values.

But try as I may, I cannot achieve this.

Fails:

```
# > pip install openpyxl
import pandas as pd

pd.read_excel(f'data.xlsx', 'firstSheetName')
# NOTE: Adding `, engine='openpyxl'` makes no difference

df_nodal.head()
```

This gives NaN in all calculate fields.

```
xl = pd.ExcelFile(f'data.xlsx')
df = xl.parse('firstSheetName')
df.head()
```

Same.

[how to read xlsx as pandas dataframe with formulas as strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58160030/how-to-read-xlsx-as-pandas-dataframe-with-formulas-as-strings)

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook(filename = f'data.xlsx')
ws = wb['mySheetName']
df = pd.DataFrame(ws.values)
df.head()
```

Now this is giving the formulae: `=H2`, `=H3` etc. in the cells.

An attempt to 'type-convert' these colums failed:

```
df[12][2:].astype(float)
# ValueError: could not convert string to float: '=H3'
```

[How to force pandas to evaluate formulas of xlsx and not read them as NaN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48041349/how-to-force-pandas-to-evaluate-formulas-of-xlsx-and-not-read-them-as-nan) might offer a solution, which involves saving and reloading the .xlsx. However I can't get it working. That syntax appears invalid.

```
import pandas as pd, xlwings as xw
def df_from_excel(path):
    book = xw.Book(path)
    book.save()
    return pd.read_excel(path,header=0)
df = df_from_excel('nodal0.xlsx')
```

This gives `XlwingsError: Make sure to have "appscript" and "psutil", dependencies of xlwings, installed.`

And `pip install appscript psutil` says they're both already installed.

Note: Same idea here: [Pandas read_excel with formulas and get values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71789086/pandas-read-excel-with-formulas-and-get-values)

I'm trying to find a way for it to *render* into a dataframe, which will then contain numeric values.

Is there any way to do it?

EDIT:

Here's what I'm dealing with:

[image]

The raw .xlsx is shown below. I've double-clicked a calculated cell revealing the underlying `=H2`.

Notice the corresponding cell of the dataframe (generated from this .xlsx) is showing `NaN`

Comment: Did you try using [`pandas.read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)? If not, see if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64986290/7109869) is of help.

Comment: What about `df = pd.read_excel(path, engine='openpyxl')`, where `path = r'C:\Users\Username\Desktop\nodal0.xlsx'` (change to your specific path)?

Comment: @GonçaloPeres I just tried ... no luck! Question updated.

Comment: In order to see if I can help would need to have access to the file.
I've built one random file to test locally, and specifying the engine in `pd.read_excel` worked well.

Comment: Alas the data is the IP of a client. Also it is a 100MB file. I've added a screenshot to the bottom of the question that shows what I'm dealing with.

Comment: Just change the type for the relevant series.

Comment: @CharlieClark How to implement? `df_nodal[12][2:].astype(float)` gives `ValueError: could not convert string to float: '=H3'`